# Proof check: if $x_n \to x$ prove $\sup(x_n) \to x$

Tags: real-analysis

My attempt,

if $x_n \to x$ then $x_n$ is bdd therefore there exists $\sup(x_n)$, by defn we have $x_n \leq \sup(x_n)$ however note that $\sup(x_n) - 1/n$ is not an upper bound hence, there exists a $n$ such that $\sup(x_n) - 1/n < x_n \leq \sup(x_n)$ and thus taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ we get by the squeezing property that $\lim_n \sup(x_n) < x \leq \lim_n \sup(x_n)$ so $\lim_n \sup(x_n) = x$?

Did I use the squeeze theorem properly? If not how can I do it using a similar method?

Comment: It looks fine to me. +1

Comment: @timbuc thanks, I was a little at unease, as I said "for some particular n", but then I take n to infinity, is that allowed?

Comment: $\sup(x_n)$ is a single number (unless I interpret your notation incorrectly), so why are you taking about the limit of it?

Comment: @HansLundmark $C_N = \displaystyle \sup_{n\geq N} x_n$, so $\lim_n \sup(x_n) = \lim_N C_N$

Comment: I understood the OP meant the $\;\lim\sup=\overline{\lim}\;$ . If this is not so I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't correct. Let $S = \sup (x_n)$. For each $n$ there exists **at least one** term of the sequence in between $S-1/n$ and $S$.  This term probably isn't $x_n$, and in fact could be the same term for different $n$.

For instance, if $x_n = 2^{-n}$, then $S = 1/2$ but $x_n \to 0$.